# Need some help with isFlush and isThreeKind methods, poker-type program

Tags: java

This isn't the complete code, but it's the parts that are causing problems. I've written both isFlush and isThreeKind, but for some reason they seem to always return true, except when the first return statement is changed to "return false", in which case they always return false. This leads to the interesting problem of the code declaring that 3000/3000 hands are flushes and contain three of a kind, something I'm fairly certain is impossible.

Edit: Yes I am a moron, I forgot to link to a pastebin of the code.

http://pastebin.com/bahwrm7Y

Comment: interesting but can you post some code?

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code for it?

Comment: Crap, sorry about that. I'm an idiot.

Comment: Maybe James is just the luckiest man alive! Can I stand next to you in the next disaster? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've added code, it appears you're passing in the entire deck each time. If that's the case, by your logic you will always have 3 of a kind (as there are 4 of each suit in the deck) and a flush (as your logic is >= 5). I suspect that if you change your logic in flush to `== 5` instead, it will always return false.

Perhaps your deck needs a `Card[] randomHand(int handSize)` method that gives you a random hand of cards, and test against that? It could even be a `Deck` object with a smaller size.

## Original answer below:

Here's my quick and dirty (and possibly inefficient) versions of those... Without seeing what you have it's going to be difficult to help debug it!

```
boolean isFlush(Card[] cards) {
    for(Card c : cards) {
        if(c.suit != cards[0].suit) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * returns the value of the set, or 0 if no three-set exists
 */
int isThreeKind(Card[] cards) {
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.length - 2; i++) {
        if(sumOfType(i.value,cards) >= 3) return i.value; // return the value of the card
    }
    return 0; // 0 indicates no value
}

int sumOfType(int value, Card[] cards) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(Card c : cards) if(value == c.value) sum++;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: ...Wow, I didn't even realize that. I had a method for that exact purpose and everything, I just didn't see that it was a full deck. Holy crap, this was a stupid question. Thanks.

Comment: @James we all do that some times. I once spent two hours crafting a post, making sure I had all my bases covered for some socket communication, and it turned out I forgot to flush my stream. Trust me, I felt ridiculously silly. There is a LOT of leg-work in programming, silly things that trip us up. In the typical 8 hour work day, we spend 4-5 of them working through "the next roadblock." It's nothing to be ashamed of, it's just the nature of programming. With more practice, you learn to find those silly mistakes and move forward more quickly. :-)